# Custom Validate Phone numbers in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, regex, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I want to validate phone numbers using a custom made Validation Class in Laravel 4.2.

Here is my code:

```
class PhoneValidationRule extends \Illuminate\Validation\Validator {

     public function validatePhone($attribute, $value, $parameters)
     {
        return preg_match("/^\+\d[0-9]{11}", $value);
     }

}

// Register your custom validation rule

Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    return new PhoneValidationRule($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

I want to accept phone numbers in international format, followed by 11 digits (All mobile phones in Kenya has 12 digits e.g +254721***661).

I have use this [useful tool](http://rubular.com/r/X3bwMTljGw) to verify the preg_match this regex.

I have then gone ahead and autoloaded the Class at `app/start/global.php` this way

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/PhoneValidator.php',

));
```

My question is, how will I use the new rule in validating an input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may call your phone validation rule by

```
'phone_number' => 'phone',
```

`Validator::make(Input::all(),['phone_number' => 'phone'])`

and move

```
//Register your custom validation rule
Validator::resolver(function ($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
   return new PhoneValidationRule($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

to `app\start\global.php`

Comment: the idea is very simple, make your custom validate method name to snake case.

Comment: I get an error message BadMethodCallException 
Method [validatePhone] does not exist.

Comment: try comporser dumpautoload if it helps

and i found out that your class is called PhoneValidatorRules but your file is PhoneValidator.php

Comment: I have added it and did composer dump-autoload. Same error message

Comment: ok, 1 question,

did you place 
`Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    return new PhoneValidationRule($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});`

in your PhoneValidationRule Class ??

please paste it to your app\start\global php file ya, else you will never register your custom validation

Comment: That error message is gone. One last question: How do I write custom error message for it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73792/discussion-between-terry-low-and-richie).