# How to validate phone number in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to validate user input phone number where number should be exactly 11 and started with 01 and value field should be number only. How do I do it using Laravel validation?

Here is my controller:

```
  public function saveUser(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|max:120',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'phone' => 'required|min:11|numeric',
            'course_id'=>'required'
            ]);

        $user = new User();
        $user->name=  $request->Input(['name']);
        $user->email=  $request->Input(['email']);
        $user->phone=  $request->Input(['phone']);
        $user->date = date('Y-m-d');
        $user->completed_status = '0';
        $user->course_id=$request->Input(['course_id']);
        $user->save();
       return redirect('success');

    }
```

Comment: I hope this will help your [php - Custom Validate Phone numbers in Laravel 4.2 - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259366/custom-validate-phone-numbers-in-laravel-4-2?answertab=votes#tab-top)

It say's 4.2 but this method is also available in 5.2

Comment: What is the problem you are getting with this code?

Comment: If the phone number to be validated should always "be exactly 11", why did you use a input field for this?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

One possible solution would to use regex.

```
'phone' => 'required|regex:/(01)[0-9]{9}/'
```

This will check the input starts with 01 and is followed by 9 numbers. By using regex you don't need the `numeric` or `size` validation rules.

If you want to reuse this validation method else where, it would be a good idea to create your own validation rule for validating phone numbers.

[Docs: Custom Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules)

In your `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot` method:

```
Validator::extend('phone_number', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return substr($value, 0, 2) == '01';
});
```

This will allow you to use the `phone_number` validation rule anywhere in your application, so your form validation could be:

```
'phone' => 'required|numeric|phone_number|size:11'
```

In your validator extension you could also check if the `$value` is numeric and 11 characters long.

Comment: Your regex is not perfect. It doesn't match from the start and it doesn't check for length, so this is also valid: `ht01123456789123456789`. This is the correct regex (as a validation rule):  `'regex:/^(\+36)[0-9]{9}$/'`.

Comment: If you write a phone number validator, it should validate every requirement a phone number must fulfill. It should also check for length and numerical values. In your current solution you need to add other rules everywhere you use it. Although it works, it isn't a well organized solution. The validator isn't complete, after the validation passes - despite its name - it doesn't tell if something is really a phone number, only that it starts with `01`.

Comment: This is no longer valid. In the Netherlands, M2M numbers have been introduced that are 12 digits long.

Comment: you can try this as well, to select any country code with plus sign along with dash: /\+([0-9][0-9])(\-)[0-9]{9}$/ , know that its input must be: +xx-xxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 73):

From Laravel 5.5 on you can use an artisan command to create a new Rule which you can code regarding your requirements to decide whether it passes or fail.

Ej:
`php artisan make:rule PhoneNumber`

Then edit `app/Rules/PhoneNumber.php`, on method passes

```
/**
 * Determine if the validation rule passes.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{

    return preg_match('%^(?:(?:\(?(?:00|\+)([1-4]\d\d|[1-9]\d?)\)?)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?)?((?:\(?\d{1,}\)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?){0,})(?:[\-\.\ \\\/]?(?:#|ext\.?|extension|x)[\-\.\ \\\/]?(\d+))?$%i', $value) && strlen($value) >= 10;
}
```

Then, use this Rule as you usually would do with the validation:

```
use App\Rules\PhoneNumber;

$request->validate([
    'name' => ['required', new PhoneNumber],
]);
```

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: It is the best answer because 1) Uses latest Laravel features 2) Supports i18n number formats

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it follows the latest approach.

Comment: in the context of laravel, this way supersedes all provided answers in this question, please push this up more

Comment: I totally agree with you guys!

Answer (score 32):

```
Validator::extend('phone', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        return preg_match('%^(?:(?:\(?(?:00|\+)([1-4]\d\d|[1-9]\d?)\)?)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?)?((?:\(?\d{1,}\)?[\-\.\ \\\/]?){0,})(?:[\-\.\ \\\/]?(?:#|ext\.?|extension|x)[\-\.\ \\\/]?(\d+))?$%i', $value) && strlen($value) >= 10;
    });

Validator::replacer('phone', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
        return str_replace(':attribute',$attribute, ':attribute is invalid phone number');
    });
```

**Usage**

Insert this code in the `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` to be booted up with your application.


This rule validates the telephone number against the given pattern above that i found after 
long search  it matches the most common mobile or telephone numbers in a lot of countries
This will allow you to use the `phone` validation rule anywhere in your application, so your form validation could be:

```
 'phone' => 'required|numeric|phone'
```

Comment: Thanks! To anyone having trouble with this, be sure to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator` to the top of `AppServiceProvider`

Comment: This should be the more accepted answer as it is more thorough than the one chosen. Then again I understand that the time at which this answer was given makes all the difference.

Comment: when the phone number is not mandatory, this solution keep throwing error message "phone is invalid phone number"

Answer (score 20):

You can use this :

```
        'mobile_number' => ['required', 'digits:10'],
```

Comment: Worked great for me, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You can try out this phone validator package. [Laravel Phone](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Phone)

**Update**

I recently discovered another package [Lavarel Phone Validator (stuyam/laravel-phone-validator)](https://github.com/stuyam/laravel-phone-validator), that uses the free Twilio phone lookup service

Answer (score 12):

Use
`required|numeric|size:11`
Instead of
`required|min:11|numeric`

Comment: I want to make only numeric input but only with 11 digits! not less or more than that actually

Comment: In your question you are asking for at least 11 numbers, if you want exactly 11 numbers you could use `required|numeric|size:11`. Consider updating your question if it is worded wrongly.

Comment: Yes @SlateEntropy is correct. Please update your question, I will update the answer.

Comment: jsut what I was looking for, this is universal, thnks

Comment: This will accept DECIMAL as well so this is not correct!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things to consider when validating a phone number if you really think about it. (especially international) so using a package is better than the accepted answer by far, and if you want something simple like a regex I would suggest using something better than what @SlateEntropy suggested. (something like [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation))

Answer (score -2):

I used the code below, and it works

```
'PHONE' => 'required|regex:/(0)[0-9]/|not_regex:/[a-z]/|min:9',
```

Comment: Please explain your solution !

Comment: regrex: a leading 0 is required | not_regex: only numbers, not alphabet | min: minimum 9

Answer (score -9):

```
$request->validate([
    'phone' => 'numeric|required',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: add "numeric" for validate only number