# Validation of Phone Number using Laravel

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-validation

i want to validate phone number like-

1.Only `Bangladesh` Mobile no is valid like, +880, 017,015,016,019,014

2 mobile no length also be valid like 11 digit

3. if prefix is 01, 13 digit if prefix is 88, 14 digit if prefix is +880

so what is the `validation` code in `laravel 6`?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36810662/8544723

Comment: not actually because i need to vaidate the bangladesh prefix +880 and bangladesh telecom company number starting with like 017,016,019,103,018,014